# Bootstrap modal(click button does not work at all)

Tags: html, ajax, jsp, servlets

I used ajax and connected select option to database. If I click the select option, then it brings database depends on the option that I chose, It worked well. But, I have closed wrong division or did something in my modal(I have no idea what I did), then the select button and modal footer button does not work at all. Can anyone help please? I am spending a thousand hours on this... but still have no idea. Can anyone please help?
(For the summary, the click button in modal does not work at all like select option and confirm button).

```
<div class="popup" > 
                <div class="container" style="margin-bottom:7px;margin-left:15px;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="float:right;background: #ffc107;height:20px;font-size:10px;width:90px;padding-top:2px;">My Branch</button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Modal -->
                  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                      <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:200px;">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-size:20px;"><strong>Branch Search</strong></h4>
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                        </div>

                        <!-- Modal: for area -->
                        <div class="modal-body" style="height:310px;">
                            <div class="left-branch">
                                <label class="label-top-title label-top-title-branch">my branch</label><br>

                                <div style="position:relative">

                                    <% if(list.isEmpty()) { %>
                                    <select name="brancharea" id="brancharea">
                                        <option value='no'>there is no branch</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <% }else { %>
                                    <select name="brancharea" id="brancharea">  

                                        <option value='0'>choose area</option> 

                                        <% for(Area a : list) { %>  
                                        <option value='<%=a.getAreaCode()%>'><%=a.getAreaName()%></option>
                                        <% } %> 
                                    </select>
                                    <% } %>
                                </div>
                                <div id="selRentDiv" class="select-branch">
                                    <ul></ul>
                                </div>      
                            </div>  

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" onclick="setBranch();"class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" style="background: #ffc107;color:white;text-align:center;margin-right:85px;">confirm</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              <!-- end of modal -->


<script>
    // after choose selec option and click confirm in modal footer. 
    function setBranch(){
        location.href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/myBranch.mb?bno="+$("#selRentDiv ul").find(":checked").val();

    }


    // choose areano and brings branch area from db
    $('#brancharea').on('change', function() {

        var areano = $(this).val();

        console.log("areano : "+areano);

        $.ajax({
            url:"branchSearch.mb?areano=" + areano,
            type:"get",
            success:function(list){  
                var value = "";     
                for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {  
                    console.log(list[i]);
                    // select option(connecting database)   


                    value += "<br>" +
                             "<input type='radio' id='rdo-" + list[i].branchNo + 
                             "' class='radio-branch' name='rdo-'" + list[i].branchNo + 
                             "' value='"  + list[i].branchNo + "'>" + 
                             " <label for='rdo-" + list[i].branchNo + "'>" +
                             list[i].branchName + "</label>" 
                }       

                return $("#selRentDiv ul").html(value);

            },
            error:function(){
                console.log("error");
            }
         });        
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Does your browser console shows any error?

Comment: there was no error in browser console. I fixed it ! I just added data-backdrop= false into the modal. Thank you for asking!